# setText of TextView on Async Task complete

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

I want to return a specific string using ksoap2 web service in my android app.

Web service is returning the correct value but the set text is not getting updated once the task is complete.  I need to do something (like trying to open the navigation drawer) then its getting updated. Any ideas??

My code is as follows

```
// Calling the async class

protected void onResume() {
            try {
                super.onResume();
                new RetrieveTimeWS().execute();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Current Time", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

Following is the Async Task

```
class RetrieveTimeWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String datetime = "";
            try {

                TextView TVcurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DateTimeNow);

                TVcurrentTime.setText("Loading...");
                datetime = getDateTimeClass.getDateTime();
                TVcurrentTime.setText(datetime);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Async Task - GetDateTime ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return datetime;
        }
    }
```

The text field shows "Loading..." only till I touch any component on the screen. How can i change the textview to the required string after the web service returns the text.

Thanks in advance.

Laks.

Comment: do it in onPostExecute(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369539/android-on-post-execute-in-asynctask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't interact with UI not from UI thread. AsyncTask has onPreExecute and PostExecute methods which called from UI thread and you can change UI in it.

```
class RetrieveTimeWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    TextView TVcurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DateTimeNow);

    Exception e;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();        
        TVcurrentTime.setText("Loading...");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String datetime = "";
        try {           
            datetime = getDateTimeClass.getDateTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.e = e;
            Log.e("Async Task - GetDateTime ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return datetime;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        if (e != null) {
            TVcurrentTime.setText(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant findviewById in AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

You can not do any UI work in background thread. Do it in onPostExecute() method.
This method runs on main thread. So, you can set text in this method.